# How can I display a warning message on the Odoo 10 website?

Tags: odoo-10

I want to make a condition of a field value in an Odoo 10 form, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to implement this function in models:

```
@api.model
    def website_form_input_filter(self, request, values):
        if 'titre' in values:
            values['titre'] = values['titre'].strip()
            if len(values['titre']) < 3:
                raise ValidationError(
                    'Text must be at least 3 characters long')
        return values
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use alert here.